# Too many low use tags makes tag soup?

Tags: discussion

I see we now have a tag for paulownia.  Nice that someone asks a question on an obscure species but I wonder if we can afford to have a tag for every one of the over 300,000 plant species?

Should this be given a more generic tag?

Or to rephrase when do we retag with a more generic tag and when do we leave well enough alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest simply not including that tag. No need to tag it generically, because then it just becomes a different class of tag soup. The tags are also not necessary in this case, because [the search can easily pick up the obscure term](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=paulownia).

Tags are more useful only when you need to organize and sort and do some complicated filtering (e.g., `[tomatoes] -[diagnosis] -[identification]` for searching for tomato questions that aren't about identifying something or a disease).